# Latex for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, latex

Does anyone know of a latex distribution/front end they highly recommend for OS X?

If the front end had some features you recommend, what are they and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2479/what-are-the-differences-between-the-many-latex-versions-available-for-os-x